# Install packages on jboss/keycloak

Tags: docker, keycloak

When running locally a [`jboss/keycloak`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) container, I try to add more software.

So far, I have tried:

```
~# yum install jq
bash: yum: command not found

~# apt-get install jq
apt-get: command not found
```

Does anybody know how can I install more software?

```
# uname -a
Linux 935559ef2e4c 4.19.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue May 26 11:42:35 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## Update #1

It looks like `microdnf` is what I have to use, but I am still getting errors:

```
root@276cdd5cc962 /]# microdnf update -y
(microdnf:1614): librhsm-WARNING **: 20:38:39.628: Found 0 entitlement certificates
(microdnf:1614): librhsm-WARNING **: 20:38:39.630: Found 0 entitlement certificates
(microdnf:1614): libdnf-WARNING **: 20:38:39.630: Loading "/etc/dnf/dnf.conf": IniParser: Can't open file
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Nothing to do.
```

The file "/etc/dnf/dnf.conf" does not exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The container itself is using [RedHats Universal Base Image](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/building_running_and_managing_containers/using_red_hat_universal_base_images_standard_minimal_and_runtimes) and seems to use [microdnf](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/microdnf) for managing software.

Check the dockerfile of jboss/keycloak (https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/dockerfile) to check, how it's done. The interesting part is:

```
RUN microdnf update -y && microdnf install -y glibc-langpack-en gzip hostname java-11-openjdk-headless openssl tar which && microdnf clean all
```

So you may try adding additional software using the *microdnf* command.

A better solution might be to create your own Dockerfile deriving from jboss/keycloak to add your additional software.

Comment: Almost there, but I am getting some errors: 

[root@276cdd5cc962 /]# microdnf update -y
(microdnf:1614): librhsm-WARNING **: 20:38:39.628: Found 0 entitlement certificates
(microdnf:1614): librhsm-WARNING **: 20:38:39.630: Found 0 entitlement certificates
(microdnf:1614): libdnf-WARNING **: 20:38:39.630: Loading "/etc/dnf/dnf.conf": IniParser: Can't open file
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Nothing to do.

The file "/etc/dnf/dnf.conf" does not exist.

Comment: I created an empty "/etc/dnf/dnf.conf" file and now it workd

Comment: This does not work as of `keycloak/keycloak:21.0`

Comment: And which package is used for the actual image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak? I want add some additional programs. Or someone know where I can find the Dockerfile. It seems a secret.

Answer (score 5):

See https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers for keycloak 21.1.X:
"Installing additional RPM packages

If you try to install new software in a stage FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak, you will notice that microdnf, dnf, and even rpm are not installed. Also, very few packages are available, only enough for a bash shell, and to run Keycloak itself. This is due to security hardening measures, which reduce the attack surface of the Keycloak container."

Comment: This should be the approved answer for `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.x`