# Keycloak Docker image basic unix commands not available

Tags: docker, keycloak, redhat

I have setup my Keycloak identification server by running a `.yml` file that uses the docker image `jboss/keycloak:9.0.0`.

Now I want get inside the container and modify some files in order to make some testing.

Unfortunately, after I got inside the running container, I realized that **some very basic UNIX commands like `sudo` or `vi` (and many many more) aren't found** (as well as commands like `apt-get` or `yum` which I used to download command packages and failed).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983069/install-packages-on-jboss-keycloak), it seems that the underlying OS of the container (**Redhat Universal Base Image**) uses the command `microdnf` to manage software, but **unfortunately** when I tried to use this command to do any action I got the following message:

> error: Failed to create: /var/cache/yum/metadata

Could you please propose any workaround for my case? I just need to use a text editor command like `vi`, and root privileges for my user (so commands like `sudo`, `su`, or `chmod`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: I would like to be able to modify the standalone.xml of the Jboss server as well generate some certificates for the server, in case that is not feasible I would like to mount these certificates and the modified standalone.xml file from my system to the container upon build

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just cp those files using on the docker file?

Comment: Yes that would be a solution but more time-consuming I guess as I would like to play around with the standalone in the container and this way I would need each and every time to rebuild the container as far as I am concerned. To achieve what you say I guess I should create a Dockerfile to extend the functionality of the keycloal image and add the cp commands, am I right?

Comment: Exactly, AFAIK for the certificates you would have to recreate the container anyway because  Keycloak builds the trushstore in beginning, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Well as long as that’s what I have for the moment, I will use that as a solution, thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: You are welcome; maybe someone else has a better solution, I would be interested to know since I have face (and still face) the same pain

Answer (score 6):

If you still, for some reason, want to `exec` in to the container try adding `--user root` to you `docker exec command`.

Just exec:ing in to the container without the `--user` will do so as user `jboss`, that user seems to have less privileges.

Comment: this answer shall be accepted

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to use approach from non docker (old school) world in the docker world. That's not right. Usually, you don't have need to go to the container and edit any config file there - that change will be very likely lost (it depends on the container configuration). Containers are configured via environment variables or volumes usually.

Example how to use TLS certificates: [Keycloak Docker HTTPS required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required/49874353#49874353)

https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/ is also good starting point to check available environment variable, which may help you achieve what you need. For example `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` enable option, when you can run Keycloak container behind a loadbalancer without you touching any config file.

I would say also adding own config files on the build is not the best option - you will have to maintain your own image. Just use volumes and "override" default config file(s) in the container with your own config file(s) from the host OS file system, e.g.:

```
-v /host-os-path/my-custom-standalone-ha.xml:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, indeed I mounted the configuration folder of the standalone containing the certificates and the modified standalone-ha.xml file in the .yml file and it seems like that's the way I should had done it in the first place.